# Cannot read symbolic link in wsl ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Whenever I try to run "*ls*" in wsl, I get the 'permission denied' error and cannot look up for my name which was created by me after the installation of wsl. It is for a Coursera course that requires the usage of a Linux environment in Windows 10.
I have already given several permissions from the 'security' tab of 'properties' in the File Explorer.[Ubuntu wsl snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBtqQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is common and normal.  These locations are not normally readable under WSL because you lack permissions to access them.  Note that Windows restricts access to some directories without additional prompting, so even if you grant additional access via Windows Explorer, that doesn't mean you'll be able to access them using WSL.  That's just how it is.

If you are trying to access your Windows user home directory, then it will usually be listed somewhere under `/mnt/c/Users`; in this case, it's likely `User1`.  If you are trying to work with a Linux environment, then you'll want to work under your WSL home directory, which will be under `/home`; you can reach it by typing `cd`.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood it. I should have used the username for Windows instead of the one for Ubuntu. But nonetheless thanks for the information.